# On row one widget align left and another align right

Tags: android, flutter

android studio 3.6

I need widget Text to be in the start of row. And risebutton to be at the end of row. 
I try this but it not help

```
new Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN / 2,
                          right: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN / 2),
                      height: Constants.MIN_HEIGHT,
                      child: new Row(children: [
                        new Text("Forgot password?",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: new Color(Constants.COLOR_PRIMARY))),
                        new Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: new RaisedButton(
                                child: Text('Sign in'.toUpperCase()),
                                color: new Color(Constants.COLOR_PRIMARY),
                                textColor: new Color(
                                    Constants.COLOR_PRIMARY_TEXT_COLOR),
                                onPressed: () {}))
                      ]))
```

here result:

[image]

Why  `Alignment.centerRight` not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Row add

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
```